# Regex to get text before pipe in Germany|fbf4cf3c-ebfe-43c8-aaf9-6811bd3488b0

Tags: regex, nintex-workflow

I have a text given in this format

```
Germany|fbf4cf3c-ebfe-43c8-aaf9-6811bd3488b0
```

How does the Regex have to look like to get `Germany` and how does the Regex have to look like to get `fbf4cf3c-ebfe-43c8-aaf9-6811bd3488b0`?

I use Nintex Workflow and tried `.+?(?=\|)`, but it's not working properly.

Comment: You can use 2 capture groups `\b(\w+)\|([a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+)\b` https://regex101.com/r/QM7yeE/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird How can I capture the first group "Germany" with Regex?

Comment: if you have a match, perhaps you can use group 1 in the replacement using `$1` or `\1`

Comment: The separate matches you could get using `\w+(?=\|[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+\b)` for Germany and `(?<=\w\|)[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+\b` for the guid

Comment: Regex are fine but it does not produce the clearest code. Maybe a simple split on character `|` will make the code more easily readable. I don't know if it exists in Nintext though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 2 capture groups and you could get the matches using `$1` and `$2`:

```
(\w+)\|([a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+)\b
```

- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word chars
- `\|` Match `|`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[a-f0-9]+` Match 1+ chars a-f 0-9
  - `(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching `-` and 1+ chars a-f o-9
- `)\b` Close group 2 followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial match

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JSIMmy/1)

To get the separate matches, you might also use lookarounds.

[Match](https://regex101.com/r/mECEGc/1) 1 or more word charactes asserting a `|` and guild like format to the right using a positive lookahead:

```
\w+(?=\|[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+\b)
```

Or [match](https://regex101.com/r/C4k0Xv/1) a guild like pattern asserting a word char followed by a `|` to the left using a positive lookbehind:

```
(?<=\w\|)[a-f0-9]+(?:-[a-f0-9]+)+\b
```